# Is meteor using the Mongo Oplog?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I check if meteor is using the oplog  of my mongo?
I have a cluster of mongo  and set two envs for my meteor.

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo/app?replicaSet=rs0
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo/local?authSource=app
```

How can I check if the opt log is actually in use. Meteor can fallback to query polling which is very inefficient but I would like to see if it's working properly with the oplog.

Any ideas?

Comment: @michel-floyd thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the relevant bits from Meteor's [`OplogObserveDriver` docs](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/oplog-observe-driver.md):

> **How to tell if your queries are using OplogObserveDriver**
>
> For now, we only have a crude way to tell how many observeChanges calls are using OplogObserveDriver, and not which calls they are.
>
> This uses the [`facts`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/facts) package, an internal Meteor package that exposes real-time metrics for the current Meteor server. In your app, run `meteor add facts`, and add the `{{> serverFacts}}` template to your app. If you are using the `autopublish` package, Meteor will automatically publish all metrics to all users. If you are not using `autopublish`, you will have to tell Meteor which users can see your metrics by calling `Facts.setUserIdFilter` in server code; for example:

```
Facts.setUserIdFilter(function (userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
  return user && user.admin;
});
```

> (When running your app locally, `Facts.setUserIdFilter(function () { return true; });` may be good enough!)
>
> Now look at your app. The facts template will render a variety of metrics; the ones we're looking for are observe-drivers-oplog and observe-drivers-polling in the mongo-livedata section. If observe-drivers-polling is zero or not rendered at all, then all of your observeChanges calls are using OplogObserveDriver!

Comment: Note that since Meteor 1.7, the `facts` package has been split into the `facts-base` and `facts-ui` package, so you'll want to add those two. https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html

Answer (score 3):

To set up oplog tailing, you need to set up a `user` on `my_database`, and an `oplog_user` on `local`. Then, specify the following URIs to connect to your replica set named `test-shard` (e.g. if there are 3 hosts named `test-shard-[0-2]`):

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://user:PASS@test-shard-0.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-1.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-2.mongodb.net:27017/my_database?ssl=true&replicaSet=test-shard&authSource=admin"
MONGO_OPLOG_URL="mongodb://oplog_user:PASS@test-shard-0.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-1.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-2.mongodb.net:27017/local?ssl=true&replicaSet=test-shard&authSource=admin"
```

On MongoDB Atlas they require `ssl=true`, and also all users authenticate through the `admin` database. On another deployment you might just authenticate through `my_database`, in which case you'd remove the `authsource=admin` for `MONGO_URL` and write `authsource=my_database` for `MONGO_OPLOG_URL`. See [this post](https://www.compose.com/articles/meteor-and-compose-a-beginners-guide-to-using-them-together/) for another example.

With MongoDB 3.6 and the Mongo node driver 3.0+, you may be able to use a succinct notation for [DNS seedlist connections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seedlist-connection-format/), e.g. on MongoDB Atlas, to specify the environment variables:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb+srv://user:PASS@foo.mongodb.net/my_database"
MONGO_OPLOG_URL="mongodb+srv://oplog_user:PASS@foo.mongodb.net/local"
```

The link above explains how this notation fills in the `ssl`, `replicaSet`, and `authSource` arguments. This is a lot nicer than the long strings above, and also means you can scale your replica set up and down without needing to reconfigure anything.

As hwillson mentioned, use the `facts-ui` and `facts-base` packages (formerly `facts`) to see if there are any `oplogObserveDriver`s running in your app. If they are all `pollingObserveDriver`, than oplog is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kadira APM to monitor your app's performance, you can see if oplogs are working by navigating to the "Live Queries" section and having a look at the "Oplog notifications" chart.

You can see in my screenshot that oplogs are working, as values appear in the chart (bottom right). If oplogs weren't working then this chart would be empty.

[image: apm oplog chart ninjapixel meteor]

Answer (score 0):

This may be very late, but this is the only way that worked for me :

```
someCollection._driver.mongo._oplogHandle
```

if this is set to null then the oplog is not enabled, otherwise you can use this handle to check for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).